# How to set the appBar color to be REALLY White?

Tags: flutter, themes, appbar

I want my app bar to be really White, still using the material 3 design.
I've tried to use
`backGroundColor: Colors.white`
either in the ThemeData of the app or directly in the widget. Nothing changes.

Here my code:

```
  static ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primaryColor: Colors.white,
    appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    ),
  );
}
```

```
return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
           elevation: 20,
           backgroundColor: Colors.white,
           title: Widget()
       )
      )
```

I don't want that Grey color. I just want the White.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSupP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you remove the elevation and also set the tintColor to "white", this will give you white.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Color.fromRGBO(255,255,255,255)`. It should work

Comment: No, it doesn't work